# How can I secure my Spring Data Rest endpoints using Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I am working with a Spring application. All is well on the browser. I can login with existing users, needing to provide only my username and password. I can also sign-up with a new user, and afterwards login in with it.

I also have available some REST endpoints which I can call. I didn't define those endpoints manually. They were created automatically, because I am using the spring-boot-starter-data-rest dependency.

The URL of a REST request would look something like http://localhost:8182/api/v1/recipes.

I am trying to get a list of recipes using Postman. I would want to get an error message like "403 Forbidden", or something like that, because I didn't provide any credentials. Instead, I receive the HTML code of the login page, and a status code of "200 OK".

This applies also after I provide the username and password as request headers (maybe I need to use another way to provide the credentials)

```
user:user
password:password
```

The following list contains a few snippets of code, to show everything I wrote in the project that is regarding the security bit of the application:

1. The first snippet of code represents the SecurityConfig class from my project:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
   public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
       @Autowired
       private UserService userService;

       @Autowired
       public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
           auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(User.PASSWORD_ENCODER);
       }

       @Override
       public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception{
           web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**");
           web.ignoring().antMatchers("/images/**");
           web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**");
       }

       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
           http.authorizeRequests()
                   .antMatchers("/sign-up").permitAll()
                   .anyRequest()
                   .hasRole("USER")
                   .and()
                   .formLogin()
                   .loginPage("/login")
                   .permitAll()
                   .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler())
                   .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler())
                   .and()
                   .logout()
                   .permitAll()
                   .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                   .and()
                   .csrf().disable();
       }

       public AuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler(){
           return (request, response, authentication) ->{
             response.sendRedirect("/recipes/");
           };
       }

       public AuthenticationFailureHandler loginFailureHandler(){
           return (request, response, exception) ->{
             request.getSession().setAttribute("flash",
                     new FlashMessage("Incorrect username and/or password. Try again.",
                             FlashMessage.Status.FAILURE));
               response.sendRedirect("/login");
           };
       }

       @Bean
       public EvaluationContextExtension securityExtension(){
           return new EvaluationContextExtensionSupport() {
               @Override
               public String getExtensionId() {
                   return "security";
               }

               @Override
               public Object getRootObject(){
                   Authentication authentication =
                           SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                   return new SecurityExpressionRoot(authentication) {
                   };
               }
           };
       }
   }
   ```
2. The second is the User entity class:

   ```
       @Entity
       public class User implements UserDetails{
           public static final PasswordEncoder PASSWORD_ENCODER =
                   new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

           @Id
           @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
           private Long id;

           @NotNull
           @Column(unique = true)
           @Size(min = 2, max = 20)
           private String username;

           @NotNull
           @Column(length = 100)
           @JsonIgnore
           private String password;

           @NotNull
           @Column(length = 100)
           @JsonIgnore
           private String matchingPassword;

           @Column(nullable = false)
           private boolean enabled;

           @OneToOne
           @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
           @JsonIgnore
           private Role role;

           @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Recipe.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
           @JoinTable(name = "users_favorite_recipes",
                   joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
                   inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id"))
           private List<Recipe> favoritedRecipes = new ArrayList<>();

           @JsonIgnore
           @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
           private List<Recipe> ownedRecipes = new ArrayList<>();

           //constructor ...
           //getters and setters ...

           public void encryptPasswords(){
               password = PASSWORD_ENCODER.encode(password);
               matchingPassword = PASSWORD_ENCODER.encode(matchingPassword);
           }

           @Override
           public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
               List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
               authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
               return authorities;
           }

           @Override
           public String getPassword() {
               return password;
           }

           @Override
           public String getUsername() {
               return username;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean isEnabled() {
               return enabled;
           }
       }
   ```
3. The third snippet represents an interface that extends the
   UserDetailsService:

   ```
   public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService{
       UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username);
       User findByUsername(String username);
       User registerNewUser(String username, boolean enabled, String password, String matchingPassword);
       void save(User user);
       List<User> findAll();
   }
   ```
4. The fourth and final snippet is an implementation of the previous
   interface (UserService):

   ```
   @Component
   @ComponentScan
   public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
       @Autowired
       private UserDao userDao;

       @Autowired
       private RoleDao roleDao;

       @Override
       public User findByUsername(String username) {
           User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
           Hibernate.initialize(user.getFavoritedRecipes());
           return user;
       }

       @Override
       public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
           throws UsernameNotFoundException{
           User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
           if(user ==  null){
               throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                 username + " was not found"
               );
           }

           return user;
       }

       @Override
       public void save(User user) {
           userDao.save(user);
       }

       @Override
       public User registerNewUser(String username, boolean enabled, String password, String matchingPassword) {
           return userDao.save(new User(username, enabled, password, matchingPassword));
       }

       @Override
       public List<User> findAll() {
           return userDao.findAll();
       }
   }
   ```

**What must I modify in this situation, in order to have a functional REST API authorization ?**

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have a **RESTful API** (with no **UI**), if that is true you can update ***SecurityConfig***#`configure(HttpSecurity http)` method replace this :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/sign-up").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .hasRole("USER")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler())
            .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler())
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}
```

By This :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, exc) ->
                        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "You are not authorized to access this resource."))
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                // Array of String that contain's all endpoints you want secure
                .antMatchers(ENDPOINTS_TO_SECURE).access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')")
                // Array of String that contain's all endpoints you want to permit
                .antMatchers(WHITE_LIST).permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        // disable page caching
        http.headers().cacheControl();
    }
```

Comment: Can I use wildcards for the antMatcher strings ?

Comment: I used the code that you provided, but not I can get all the recipe entities, without providing any username or password (using REST). Also, the login page isn't displayed anymore if I try to access the root endpoint from the browser (http://localhost:8182/)

Comment: Ahah I see, so you have a UI then ! like I said in my response This is for RESTful API security, yes you can have path with wildcards ( like `"/recipes/**"` )

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your own authentication entry point, to get 403 messages, you can use Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint.

Example:.

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Adding `.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/sign-up").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());
    }
}
```

Now when I try to access `http://localhost:8080/test`, I get `403 Access Denied` message.

Comment: I added the `.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());` line at the end of the `configure` method. I get the `403 Access Denied` message. But if I access the http://localhost:8182/ root endpoint from the browser, it will give me the same error, instead of redirecting me to the login page. If I use the http://localhost:8182/login endpoint however, all is well and I can login with any available user. I think we are close to resolve this. There is only the root endpoint problem. How must I provide the credentials within a REST client like Postman ?

Comment: I need to specify that I still didn't add any endpoints of my own. I am still using automatically generated REST endpoints, which would be my desired outcome in this case.

Comment: Rest endpoint that I added was only for demonstration purposes (it's not needed for you obviously). You need to write a custom entry point or override Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint since you need root to redirect to login instead of getting 403.

Comment: Can you provide some code on how you would create that custom entry, or override the Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint ? Also, how do I need to provide the credentials in a rest client like Postman, in order to be authorized, and get the required data ?